# Adding title tag to hyperlinks placed in bulleted list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a bulleted list set to `BulletedListDisplayMode.HyperLink` display mode, and it works fine but I cannot find a way to specify the title tag for each hyperlink. Can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box as under the hood BulletedList binds to a ListItem which does not have any such property.

You can deal with this a few ways -

1) Handle the OnPreRender event, loop through all items and add using Attributes.Add()

2) Create a custom control which inherits from BulletedList and add a title property.

3) Get rid of the BulletList all together and use a Repeater

Personally I would go for 3) as you then have much more flexibility in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `BulletedList.AddAttributesToRender` method?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.addattributestorender.aspx